# How to stub constant functions when using ES Modules with sinon.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

With ES Modules, we define some exported functions as `const` and it is often a standard practice. However, during unit testing, these const functions can't be stubbed out which seems problematic from a unit testing perspective. For example,

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

import { bindNodeCallback } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// readFile :: string, string => Observable<string>
export const readFile$ = bindNodeCallback(fs.readFile);

// readJson :: string => Observable<any>
export function readJson(fileName) {
    return readFile$(fileName, 'utf-8')
        .pipe(map((rawFile) => JSON.parse(rawFile)));
}
```

Now to unit test readJson, I would typically want to stub `readFile$` function. Unfortunately, following Sinon code doesn't work:

```
// Setup data - stubs / mocks
const stub = sinon.stub(myFs, 'readFile$').returns(json$);
```

Since Sinon is simply changing reference `myFs.readFile$`, original `const` still points to the original function which is in turn called by `readJson` function.

**Any suggestion - how can I really stub/mock constant function within the same module?**

Comment: A would be very useful if you showed how `myFs` was imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is constant one can't change it using "normal" code. Unfortunately `sinon` is not magic. You need to instrument your code to allow changing constant value.

Assuming you are using babel to transpile you could use [`babel-plugin-rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-rewire).

After adding it to your babel config you would be able to do the following injection in your test code

```
import { default as readJson, __RewireAPI__ as rewire } from './path/to/readJson.js'

const stub = sinon.stub(myFs, 'readFile$').returns(json$)
rewire.__set__('readFile$', stub)

// readJson() would now call provided stub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sinon has a way to do this, without the use of third party packages (e.g. Babel).  Here is their documentation page about it, with a simple example:  [How to stub a dependency of a module](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/stub-dependency/).  I just tried it myself and it seems to work.

Sorry, I don't have time to share any code here in my reply.  I know that is poor form :-/  But hopefully the link helps some people.

Comment: You can only mock CommonJS modules used by Node.js. It still doesn't allow us to mock ES6 modules which are static in nature.

Comment: OK right.  What if, before executing your test file in Node, you Browserify your test file and the module-under-test into a new bundled file, then execute the bundled file in Node?  That's what I'm doing now, and I'm able to do what you've described, using ES6 modules and the Sinon dependency stub method.