# How do you call an external function in enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I have a standard react component with external functions that I am either calling or want to check if they have been called

i know i can do `wrapper.instance().funcName()` for class function but say I have imported an external function, either as a prop or as a straight import, how do I do this?

basically how do i do the below???

```
class component extends React.Component{

   localMethod = () => {
     externalMethod()
   }
}

expect(externalMethod).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: "I have a standard react component with external functions that I am either calling or want to check if they have been called" speaking of unit-testing. You don't really want to call external function in your test because you are testing component not the function. Also you don't want to check if a component called some external function it privately imports because it is implementation detail not a part of component API to be tested in unit-test.

Comment: But if you ensist you need to check this implementation detail you could follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461194/351705)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko so this kind of thing isn't really done? not even props from redux? not sure how I can test my stuff then

Comment: "not even props from redux?" if you passing a callback a property you could always pass a stub (google for `sinon`) and check it was actually called.

Comment: "so this kind of thing isn't really done?" it can be done (check the answer I've linked above). But the amount of work to instument you imports is somewhat annoying. Also those tests relying on implementation details are highly like to break.

Comment: yeh im pretty awful with sinon. I know I can spy on a method though. but is it just a case a of spying on the prop and then expecting it to be called. or do you have link to relevant docs? i know to google sinon but wouldn't be sure which parts

Comment: [Stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.0.0/stubs/)

Comment: Also you might not need sinon if you are already using jest https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

It would be your Component, it would easy (but your seems not! sorry):
Your MyComponent **depend** on this externalMethod.
So to be easy to test, your component should allow to inject this **dependency**.
This allow your test to provide a spy for this method.

Your test code: (following the [Arrange Act Assert Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert))

```
// Arrange: create a jest spy
const externalMethodSpy = jest.fn();

wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent externalMethod={externalMethodSpy} />);
// Act on your wrapper ...

// Assert the result
expect(externalMethodSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Your production code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
   localMethod = () => {
     this.props.externalMethod()
   }
   ...
}
```